# Взаимодействие процессов C#

Tags: c#, wcf, процесс

Имеется следующая задача: есть процесс A(приложение), который принимает и обрабатывает некоторые данные из базы данных. Есть другой процесс - B, который должен уметь запрашивать эти данные и в дальнейшем работать с ними - по большому счету, процесс B должен получить от A некий настроенный объект для работы с данными и обновлениями(событиями)(только через A). Как лучше реализовать решение подобного рода, только через WCF? Нет ли каких-то более нативных решений?

Comment: Что вы вкладываете в понятие "нативность"?

Comment: Shared memory, socket, named pipe. Вроде ничего не забыл... Выбирайте что вам более по нраву.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Хотелось бы выбрать решение на стыке хорошей производительности и высокой скорости разработки. Что в этом случае Вы могли бы посоветовать? p.s. нативный - более низкоуровневый.

Comment: Оба приложения на одной машине будут работать или на разных?

Comment: В любом случае берите WCF - он позволяет использовать самые разные протоколы, в том числе очень быстрые пайпы. Но если вдруг понадобится прикрутить взаимодействие с процессом на другой системе и даже написанном на другом языке - это легко добавить, используя WCF.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov очень быстрые пайпы это, интересно, как? Своя какая-то реализация не опираясь на системные?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов - я имел в виду стандартные пайпы. Они быстрые по сравнению с http, tcp, soap и тому подобным. Пайпы - самое быстрое из того, что есть в WCF по умолчанию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для решения подобных задач обычно используют шину данных, например такие как NServiceBus или MassTransit. Подобный вариант реализации позволит вам реализовать общение 2-х процессов даже если они будут находится на разных машинах. Так же у вас будет из коробки гарантия доставки сообщения, а так же много других полезных возможностей.

Comment: Данные шины, к сожалению, работают только с RabbitMQ или подобными системами. Очень важна скорость обмена данными между процессами(она должна стремится к тому, как если бы это был один процесс и один APPDomain). На данный момент самым быстрым транспортом является IPC из Remoting, несмотря на все рюшки WCF. Но каких-либо библиотек, облегчающих работу с ним, мне , к сожалению. найти не удалось.

Comment: Если вам в вашей задаче не может помочь сервисная шина, то либо https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx либо вам нужно пересмотреть архитектуру решения.

Comment: А почему IPCChannel вы не рассматриваете как возможное решение?

Comment: По тому, что там сообщения сериализуются\дессериализуются, т.е. дофига оверхеда. Если не подходит шина, то и этот вариант вряд ли может подойти.

Comment: Ну про дофига оверхеда - соглашусь, надо делать полноценную реализацию прокси-объекта.

Comment: Чего хотелось бы добиться - так этого общего объекта у двух процессов, который имеет права на изменение у одного процесса и доступен для чтения(все свойства и события) для другого. Подобных реализаций или прототипов найти не удается.

Comment: @Sleeeper чем вам не подходит использование общей памяти?

Comment: Решение-то может быть и подошло бы, но уж слишком много накладных расходов.  А тот же IPCChannel использует ту же общую память.Только вот адекватных примеров нет.

Comment: @Sleeeper нет, IPCChannel не использует общую память. IPCChannel, грубо говоря, уже не актуальная технология, вместо которой MS рекомендует использовать WCF.

Comment: А в чем преимущество WCF  в части скорости? Или преимущество той же общей памяти относительно IPCChannel?

Comment: @Sleeeper в случае с общей памятью меньше всего оверхеда.

Comment: А по части скорости? WCF, общая память и IPCChannel

Comment: @Sleeeper поищите в интернете замеры. Я их не делал.

Comment: Искал) если бы нашел - не спрашивал бы)